# salesforce sandbox cURL request invalid grant_type

Tags: curl, salesforce

I am trying to access a salesforce sandbox account using a cURL request. I have created a similar cURL request using a separate salesforce developer account which has worked successfully; however, upon modifying the information from that request I get an error: invalid grant_type response. Below are the two request. The first is the working request and the second is the sandbox account which has the invalid grant_type error.

1 WORKS
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d grant_type=password -d        "client_id=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv_ab" -d "client_secret=1234567891011121314" -d "username=someone@email.com" -d "password=passwordxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-Prettyprint:1"

2.DOES NOT WORK
curl https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d grant_type=password -d "client_id=zxcvbnmasdfghjklqwertyuiopzxcvbnmasdfghjklqwertyuiop" -d "client_secret=7845679304-1945678" -d "username=someone@email.com.sandbox -d "password=passwordxxxxxxxxxxxxx” -H "X-Prettyprint:1"

where xxxxxxxx=security token

The two requests are almost identical but with different client_id client_secret username and password. They also have slightly different urls.

My guess is that there is something that I have to enable/disable from the sandbox account to allow these types of requests. However, I'm not sure and would appreciate help in determining a solution to this problem.

EDIT: 
When I make the request to the sandbox I get the follow message

```
 {
 "error_description" : "grant type not supported",
 "error" : "unsupported_grant_type"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The client Id from a production organization won't work with a sandbox organization and vice versa.

So, you will need to setup a new app in a sandbox Org to get a client_id that will work in a sandbox.

Comment: I have a new app in the sandbox with a new client_id. I tried to illustrate that in the above example, but, perhaps it wasn't very clear. The client_secret is also new for the sandbox connected app. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Jaskaye17 You are missing the closing quote on the -d username in the question. Do the sandbox credentials work for the normal Salesforce login screen?

Comment: the credentials work for the normal salesforce login screen. I have also made the cURL request with the closing quote on the -d username portion. Additionally, I am getting the following response message: {
  "error_description" : "grant type not supported",
  "error" : "unsupported_grant_type"
}

Comment: There are different tokens between sandbox and prod.