# getting 400 statusCode while connecting to salesforce using HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am trying to connect to salesforce sandbox environment but I am getting a status code 400 error. Below is my code.

my login endpont is:https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Login()
        {
            String jsonResponse;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"grant_type", "password"},
                    {"client_id", clientId},
                    {"client_secret", clientSecret},
                    {"username", userName},
                    {"password", password}
                });

                request.Headers.Add("X-PrettyPrint", "1");

                var response = client.PostAsync(loginEndpoint, request).Result;
                jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }

            var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonResponse);
            return values;
        }
```

Comment: What does the body of the response return. There should be a message describing the problem. for example `"error": "unsupported_grant_type", "error_description": "grant type not supported"`

Comment: BAD REQUEST.....

Comment: Is that the raw response? I just tested it from a browser and got back full xml rep of the json in my previous comment.

Comment: This question had a similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691682/salesforce-sandbox-curl-request-invalid-grant-type